# How can I have a trigger without my command prefix, like welcome and not $welcome?

Tags: discord, bots

So I wanted to make a feature on my discord bot and I wanted it to respond when users say welcome and say Welcome! back. But every time I try it only responds to $welcome. ($ is my prefix). What should I do?

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "$")

@client.command()
async def welcome(ctx, message):
    if any(word in message for word in welcome):
        await message.channel.send("Welcome!")
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
     if "welcome" in message.content:
           await message.channel.send('Welcome!')
```

Comment: any way I can make it respond if a user say Welcome or WELCOME? Thanks.

Comment: if "welcome" in message.content.lower()

Comment: Thanks but it keeps looping and saying welcome over and over again, stops, and does it again. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Make sure the person saying welcome isn't a bot

Comment: What do you mean? The bot or the person? Anyways I'm saying "welcome" and the bot replies with "Welcome!" but keeps repeating itself.